# Big Query Job state done before the query finishes

Tags: scala, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, cats-effect

I have a scala application that creates a tsv table using BigQuery. When a user tries to access the data I want to return it if the query job is finished, otherwise tell them it's still running.

My query job creation looks like this:

```
        bigQuery.create(
          JobInfo.of(
            QueryJobConfiguration
              .newBuilder(mySql)
              .setAllowLargeResults(true)
              .setDestinationTable(TableId.of("MyReports", s"${tableName}_$random".replace("-", "_")))
              .setWriteDisposition(JobInfo.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
              .setCreateDisposition(JobInfo.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
              .setUseLegacySql(false)
              .build()
          )
        )
```

and the method to get the data looks like this:

```
override def getData(jobId: String): IO[Either[Throwable, String]] = {
  bigQueryService.getMyJob(jobId).map {
    case Right(None) | Right(Some(null)) => Right("Data not found, check provided job name")
    case Right(Some(r)) =>
      if (r.isDone) {
        Try(r.getQueryResults()
        .iterateAll()
        .asScala
        .map(_.asScala.map(_.getValue.toString).mkString("\t"))
        .mkString("\n")
        ).toEither
      } else {
        Right(s"Job not completed, current status is ${r.getStatus.getState.toString}")
      }
    case Left(err: Throwable) => Left(err)
  }
}
```

Where I'm using Cats Effect IO to evaluate at the end of computation. My problem is that the `getQueryResults` method on a job stalls until the query is finished. I try to prevent this by checking another method on a BQ Job: `isDone`. For some reason in my testing, `isDone` returns true before the query has completed. I see this myself when checking the BigQuery console. This results in a user's request always stalling until the query completes, instead of returning a message as intended.

How is it a job can be completed while the query still runs? Am I missing some distinction between jobs and queries? Or is there something else I've missed? Thank you for any suggestions you may have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jobs.getQueryResults` has an optional `timeoutMs` parameter which governs its hanging GET semantics.  It waits for job completion up to that specified interval or 10 seconds if not specified.  If the job is complete it returns immediately regardless.

If you set the timeout to zero it will return the response immediate, and you can check the result stats to see if the job is complete.  If so, the response should also contain the schema and first page of data rows.

Additional information from the REST reference: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my current implementation, the request hangs until the query completes, which is longer than 10 seconds. Any idea why this is the case? Also, why `isDone` evaluates as true while the query still runs?

Comment: Not enough information.  Is the query ending in error?  That would be a case where the job is in the done state, yet there are no query results available.  Similarly, a SQL DDL query would do the same as DDL doesn't return results either.

Comment: As far as running long, you're relying on a library abstraction that likely polls on your behalf, rather than the low level API contract.

Comment: The job runs successfully, and since it queries a large table just takes a few min to complete. `bigQueryService.getMyJob` is only returning the Job object, any polling is done through BigQuery's java client. `isDone` is a method provided for a Job object by google.

Comment: I'm trying to set `maxWaitTime` to 0 sec as a parameter for `getQueryResults` and then checking for the schema to see if it's completed. I'll report back if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Setting `maxWaitTime` worked, and now for some reason `isDone` is behaving as expected, returning RUNNING as the jobState while the query runs. Perhaps evaluating the IO causes it to wait for the job if no `maxWaitTime` is set? Really not sure. Anyways, thanks @shollyman